# Reading a BIG File in Java

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm trying to read  2GB file using the following program. The thing is i want to read a file and then append it in a single string which passes to the program for further processing.  this application will deploy to Jenkins where i can't increase the memory size. Wondering, if i can process the file into small pieaces and then process it

When i append the line into String builder i got memoryOutOFBound exception.

```
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
          try {
           FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("E:"+File.separator+"file"+File.separator+"File.text");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
                build.append(strLine);
            }

            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any idea how to parse the Big File into string? or should i read the file into smaller chunks and then process it?

Comment: Share details about your runtime environment in your post. For a 2gb file you want > 3gb assigned to your vm. The string has to go into memory if you insist on using a string.

Comment: Try increasing heap size for your application

Comment: You may well find that you *can't* do this, even with a bigger heap size - if the 2GB file is all ASCII, you'll end up with a 4GB string in memory... which may push some VM limits, even if you have enough memory. Could you process a `List<String>` with each line as a separate string instead?

Comment: The problem this application will deploy to Jenkins where i can't increase the memory size. Wondering, if i can process the file into small pieaces and then process it

Comment: Remember to mention things like Jenkins next time, if you don't give all the information, it's really difficult to help you.

Comment: Processing the file in small chunks - ideally as a stream - would be better. Unfortunately you haven't told us anything about what you need to do with the data, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. one approach is to use a scanner and look for particular text you want, then process that portion then move to next. BTW you can use the approach mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600422/method-to-find-string-inside-of-the-text-file-then-getting-the-following-lines)

Comment: Not only will a 2GB ASCII file end up as a 4GB `String` - the moment the `StringBuilder` extends its array from 2GB to 4GB you'll need at least 6GB of heap to do the copy-operation!!! Really scary, you should definitely go for smaller chunks.

Comment: Since Java uses integers as array indexes no array can be longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE, so even with a 16GB heap you could come into troubles...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with increasing memory of JVM. You can do this by providing VM arguments as :  `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m`

The -Xms argument sets the initial and minimum heap memory size for the JVM.
The -Xmx argument defines the max memory size that the heap can reach for the JVM.

`-Xms<size>` set initial Java heap size

`-Xmx<size>` set maximum Java heap size

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 7** then you can use the `Files` class:

`List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Single `String`:

```
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// or equivalently:
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(path)));
```

**JAVA 8:**

You don't need any external class. Use the `Stream`:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(myPath)) {
    list = lines.collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
}
```

Or you can use third party libraries

**Guava**

`com.google.common.io.Files` contains many useful methods.

```
String toString(File, Charset)
```

or

```
List<String> readLines(File, Charset)
```

**Apache CommonsI/O**

`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` also offer similar functionality:

`String toString(InputStream, String encoding)`

`List readLines(InputStream, String encoding)`

For me `Guava` works great for similar implementation.

Comment: Those are nice alternatives for reading the file but I fail to see how this addresses the memory-issue which is the core part of the question.