# Searching txt in a file using java

Tags: java

Searching txt in a file using java

This is my txt file

> "hhhead":"Melvin","respondent":"Edlen"

I Want to search hhhead and program will return Melvin

how can I do that?

Comment: You could easily use `String.split(",")` and a `Map` for the data. What have you tried so far, code wise?

Comment: nothing so far. i just want to think before i code.

Comment: "hhhead":"Melvin","respondent":"Edlen","int_date":"2017-06-15","start_time":"09:46","interviewer":"Kit","house_type":"1","nbr":2,"nstorey":1,"roof":"1","wall":"2","floor":"7","nnucfam":1,"phsize":5,"hpq_mem":[{"memno":"1","msname":"Malabarbas","mfname":"Melvin","mmname":"Pirneto","reln":"1","reln_o":"","nucfam":"1","sex":"1","birth_date":"1969-12-18"

Comment: heres more.  all i want is that if i search hhhead it will return Melvin and if i search respondent it will return Edlen.

Comment: @Shaine Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600442/599528) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15577756/599528)

Comment: can u help me with this?

Comment: thanks.. i know how to search hhhead but dont know how to return melvin.

Comment: @Shaine Whatever code you have written, copy and paste here by editing your question and then ask where exactly you are stuck rather than asking solution.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {

  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {

   String sCurrentLine;
                        String Seach="hhhead";
   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if(sCurrentLine.contains(Seach)){
    System.out.println("hhhead FOUND!!");
                            }
   }

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }`

Comment: Share your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the code ready to read the `.txt` file and write into a string.

In the below code, str is the string having text file content.

```
String str = "\"hhhead\":\"Melvin\",\"respondent\":\"Edlen\",\"int_date\":\"2017-06-1\u200C\u200B5\",\"start_time\":\"09:\u200C\u200B46\",\"interviewer\":\"K\u200C\u200Bit\",\"house_type\":\"1\"\u200C\u200B,\"nbr\":2,\"nstorey\":1\u200C\u200B,\"roof\":\"1\",\"wall\":\"\u200C\u200B2\",\"floor\":\"7\",\"nnuc\u200C\u200Bfam\":1,\"phsize\":5,\"h\u200C\u200Bpq_mem\":[{\"memno\":\"1\u200C\u200B\",\"msname\":\"Malabarb\u200C\u200Bas\",\"mfname\":\"Melvin\u200C\u200B\",\"mmname\":\"Pirneto\"\u200C\u200B,\"reln\":\"1\",\"reln_o\"\u200C\u200B:\"\",\"nucfam\":\"1\",\"se\u200C\u200Bx\":\"1\",\"birth_date\":\u200C\u200B\"1969-12-18\"";
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String[] split = str.split(",");
        for(String s: split){
            String[] split2 = s.split(":");
            map.put(split2[0], split2[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(map.get("\"hhhead\""));
```

I copied the data from your comments and had to use backslash("\") to escape string, used split method having "," as an argument and stored in to a key-value map. If you search with the key, `"\"hhhead\""` you get `"Melvin"`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to see it helped you! Feel free to mark as an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: yes very helpfull nothing i can say. all i want is all here in ur code. thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and parse the data.

Then you can store the data in key-value pairs like a `Map` then you can easily get it.

Comment: @Shaine We are not here to write code for you. If you face any problem then people might try to help you. Don't ask for code without putting your own efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {

        String sCurrentLine;
                    String Seach="hhhead";
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if(sCurrentLine.contains(Seach)){
            System.out.println("hhhead FOUND!!");
                        }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: in System.out.println("hhhead FOUND!!");

Comment: With all due respect, answers are for solutions to your question. So what you should do is copy and paste your code by editing the question and should delete this answer.