# java how to skip into file until hex string?

Tags: java

I inherited a java program with the source code and need to make some changes, but have no idea what I am doing. sorry

file I need to read is already loaded
I need to be able to in.skip into the file until hex string of 0xFFFF

I have tried many different commands but have not got any positive results

sorry for not giving code, but not sure what to even post.

Comment: There is no builtin method for that. *You* need to read the data and check for the value you're looking for.

Comment: could you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: Try to take a quick course online.  There are lots to choose from but I'd recommend the ones on Linkedin.  Programming is not that hard to learn but there is a lot to learn and not knowing the basics will cause you to waste a lot of time.  The courses will get you up to speed fast.  Good luck.

Comment: You can check some answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600422/method-to-find-string-inside-of-the-text-file-then-getting-the-following-lines